# how to add a hyperlink to a webpage in the MS word comment using c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-word

I can only create a hyperlink in the document. But I want to create it in the comment box. How can this be done?

Comment: Please read the site guidelines for asking questions in the [help]. StackOverflow is not a tutorial or free code-writing service. You need to provide more detail (does the comment already exist or a new comment? If the latter, how to locate it?), what you've tried (code!) and describe how it doesn't work. Also, for this question, the version of Word involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest checking out the Open XML SDK. It allows .NET apps to create or modify MS Office files. Here's where to get started:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx